Car being towed on a flatbed truck was improperly secured - what damages to look out for?
Had this car towed on a flatbed truck, but it was improperly secured. Did not know that the hauler was not doing it right at that time or else I would have intervened.
It was only through reading up about flatbed towing afterwards that I realized just how wrong the hauler was.
I am seeking any advice now on what could be potentially damaged, or just generally, out of whack now in the car as a result of this tow.
Photos of the towing set up:


The car was driven, not winched, up the flatbed platform. It had one fully flat, punctured rear left tyre. The tyre got punctured while driving on the freeway, which resulted in the car needing to be towed out. You might be able to spot that punctured tyre in the first photo.
None of the 4 wheels on the car were strapped down to the platform. There was just the winch-line being hooked to the front right wheel using a strap as per the second photo.
When the hauler raised up the flatbed platform, the car actually slid backwards a little but it stopped sliding further due to the front right wheel being held by the winch line.

The gap in the wheel well of the front right tyre looks unusually large and I cannot tell if it is due to this wrong setup or the rear left tyre being flat and letting the suspension on the front right extend a little.
The ride on the flatbed truck was extremely bumpy due to poor road conditions, and the Hauler was not gentle when crossing speed bumps, so the car was subjected to a lot of shocks and vibrations.
Although I would be bringing the car in to the dealer's workshop for a check, I would like to hear your thoughts on this first.
I'm particularly concerned about any weakening of the components that may not manifest as any problems now, but could lead to some major break down later on.
As it turns out, having your own knowledge about these things is so important as you never know when you would find yourself in a sticky situation.

Is the left side of the car really that shape? Or is it out of whack from a collision? If so, the geometry will need looking at anyway. And is an off-centre pull on one wheel going to put more force on the suspension components than hard cornering would?

I'm also wondering why you think there'd be some kind of damaged caused from an extremely bumpy ride on the back of a flatbed truck? The car would still be on its own suspension as well as on the trucks suspension. That seems like it would be a pretty cushy ride for it in the long run. Maybe that's just me?

I don't see anything that bad there. Whether it was winched up or driven it was still going to roll on the flat, which was going to need to be replaced anyway.

The car was tugged at just one front wheel instead of being tied down on all 4 of its wheels. That one front right wheel that was strapped to the winchline would be bearing all the strain from any potential displacement or movement of the car.
Don't know why it doesn't look troubling to you when it is clearly standard and necessary for cars to be secured on all 4 wheels when towed on a flatbed: .https://www.wikihow.com/Tie-Down-a-Car-on-a-Trailer#/Image:Tie-Down-a-Car-on-a-Trailer-Step-11.jpg.
Clearly the hauler was being sloppy and did not secure the car up to standard on his truck.

@GdD I am not concerned about the tyre that went flat
